# Google map crash with jetpack compose library

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to add google maps to my app following this document - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/maps-compose

The problem is when I set is `isMyLocationEnabled = true` I got this error, I want to display myLocation button, when it is to false it is working

```
    Process: com.example.tryingtofixgooglemap, PID: 12872
    java.lang.SecurityException: my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bi.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):27)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):138)
        at cy.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1043)
...
...
```

I got both permissions in my manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tryingtofixgooglemap">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TryingToFixGoogleMap">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="{api_key}" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TryingToFixGoogleMap">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is my build.gradle

```
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation "com.google.maps.android:maps-compose:1.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1'
```

And my code in compose scope

```
var uiSettings by remember { mutableStateOf(
                            MapUiSettings(
                                zoomControlsEnabled = false,
                            )
                        )
                    }
                    var properties by remember { mutableStateOf(
                            MapProperties(
                            isMyLocationEnabled = true
                            )
                        )
                    }
                    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                        GoogleMap(
                            modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize(),
                            properties = properties,
                            uiSettings = uiSettings
                        ){

                        }


                    }
```

Comment: are you checking for permissions on run time?

Comment: Not explicitly, I thought that this new library would do it itself, and pop up window on phone screen to allow/not allow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of google's accompanist library to check for run time permission with jetpack compose

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-permissions:<version>"
```

Declare Permission State

```
val permissionState = rememberPermissionState(
    permission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
)
```

On Tap of a button or a lifecycle event you can request run time permissions

```
Button(onClick = { state.launchPermissionRequest() }) {
    Text("Request Permission")
}
```

Listen for the permission result from permissionState flow

```
if (permissionState.hasPermission) {
    // do something
}
```

ref: https://google.github.io/accompanist/permissions/